# Accessibility Event - Catch when announcement is finished

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm trying to set up some features for the visually impaired.
I succeeded in producing an announcement via sendAccessibilityEvent, following I need to start the voice recognition service.
Separately they work perfectly, but I'm not able to wait for the announce to be finished to start the voice recognition.
Any idea on how to determine when the Accessibility Manager finished his job?

thank you!

A